# Python failed to install using pip3 install ---upgrade tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Am using sumsung N 100 SP netbook,j installed latest python 3.6.1 but on Wed installing python it refused.
 The processor is Atom  32 bit 1.6GHz, windows 7 x86, Ram 2GB

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question with 

sufficient and specific information to describe your problem.

Comment: To be specific, can you add the error log from your installation attempt?